# Вызов Bottom Sheet до версии 5.0

Tags: android, recyclerview, bottom-sheet

Сразу оговорюсь - что подобный вопрос уже поднимал, но ответа на него не было дано, и попробую заново его поднять - переформулировав.

Есть список `RecyclerView`, в каждом айтеме которого есть кнопка `i` (вызов информации).

При нажатии на эту кнопку появляется элемент `Bottom Sheet`, содержащий в себе некую, необходимую мне информацию.

Поскольку `Bottom Sheet` нельзя просто взять и вызвать, как захочется - а его необходимо привязать к `Coordinator Layout` и указать `Behavior` (`Behavior` - это класс, который управляет поведением появления\исчезновения и тп. данного элемента).

Раз все это дело вызывается в списке, который в свою очередь находится в фрагменте - в голову сразу приходит мысль, что придется долго и мучительно пробрасывать этот `Behavior` по фрагменту\списку\адаптеру, и следить везде за тем, чтобы он не был старым\null и прочие неприятные вещи.

Для этого я вынес обработку `Behavior` в отдельный класс-хелпер, и все необходимые действия делаю через него - использовав синглтон могу вызывать где нужно и делать что нужно.

И всё вроде бы ничего, да вот только на версиях ниже 5.0 он по нажатию кнопки `i` не вызывается(отмечу, что на версиях 5.0 и выше работает все как нужно, что и удивляет). Сей баг исправляется перемоткой таба в сторону, ощущение, словно он застревает.

Это очень неприятный баг над которым мучаюсь примерно 3 недели, на данный вопрос вынесу премию на 150 репы.

Минимальную инфу я выложу, по мере надобности - говорите что нужно, и так громоздко получилось.

MainActivity инициализация:

```
   private void initBottomSheetBehavior() {
        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator);

        bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.framesheet);
        behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        BottomSheetHelper.instance().setBehavior(behavior);
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

                if (behavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                    behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                }
                //   saveState(newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

            }
        });


    }
```

Сам хелпер:

```
public class BottomSheetHelper {

    private BottomSheetBehavior behavior;
    private static BottomSheetHelper instance;

    private BottomSheetHelper() {
    }

    public synchronized static BottomSheetHelper instance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new BottomSheetHelper();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public BottomSheetBehavior getBehavior() {
        return behavior;
    }

    public void setBehavior(BottomSheetBehavior behavior) {
        this.behavior = behavior;
        //поскольку находится в главной разметке, то элемент появляется сразу, необходимо, что-бы скрывать "самовольное" появление простыни.
        this.behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
    }
}
```

Класс адаптера, обработка нажатия на `i`:

```
   holder.info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BottomSheetHelper.instance().getBehavior().setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    });
```

Comment: А не проще прокинуть колбэк по нажатию кнопки и принимать его в активити, которая и выводит ботомшит?

Comment: ну кончено проще и с тем что я вижу выше - лучше. Сделайте мост между адаптером и activity, здесь обычный interface callback - подходит. А то что по версии некорректная работа, убедитесь что используйте Android Support Library 23.2+ где-то в марте было обновление, всё отлично работает.

Comment: Дак почему данный способ не работает на версиях ниже 5?Так то оно работает вполне так, как я и ожидал. Но на 4.0+ после прокрутки вниз списка - он перестает вызываться.

Comment: @pavlofff это не решает моей проблемы, будь ошибка в логике - то он бы не работал нигде. В моем случае на версиях лолипоп все работает, как нужно. Пускай решение не самое красивое - но рабочее. Потом во время рефакторинга исправлю.